# Force exerted on the CPU socket by heatsink

Tags: design, finite-element-method

I am currently designing a replacement bracket for AM4 CPU coolers that will be compatible with different cooler models and allow them to be installed facing different directions, as AM4 socket is non-symmetrical, and the current design looks like this:

[image: Mounting bracket]

This a draft and I want to use FEM to reduce the amount of metal covering, so more air could get through and also cool the VRM's and other chips in the CPU vicinity, but to do that I need to know what is the maximum force I need to design for. I think calculations using just the mass of the cooler would not be accurate, as I also have to take into account the force exerted by screws that are used to hold heatsink in place.

tl;dr: how much force should I account for when designing mounting bracket for CPU cooler?

Comment: Do I understand it right that you want to put the mounting bracket on the "CPU side" of the mainboard? All mounting brackets I have ever seen were on the back side, where air flow is not an issue

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. This bracket is supposed to go on the CPU side.